# Rewrite specific rule (html url to php, with https)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I inherited a project with a huge htaccess file doing a lot of rewrites from ".html" urls to php files like this:

```
RewriteRule ^login\.html$ login.php
```

I know there a lot of similar questions around the site, but none of them worked in my case, most of them are just http -> https rewrites/redirections.

I just want to change **only that specific rule** with the following behaviour:

1.- http://www.example.com/login.html --> should go to --> https://www.example.com/login.html

2.- https://www.example.com/login.html --> should map to login.php file (like in the rewrite above).

htaccess solution prefered, but any others would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.html$ https://www.example.com/login.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^login\.html$ login.php
```

Also, check in your in .conf files, that `DocumentRoot` is the same for `*:80` and `:443` VirtualHosts, and that both have `AllowOverride All`

(In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file.)

Comment: I have, Do you suggest a better solution? There isn't any way to avoid hardcoding the domain name? %{HTTP_HOST} maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can use `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: The better solution is to put those rules in .conf file. The only difference is that pattern should then begin with `/`, so `RewriteRule ^/login...`.

Comment: The first rewrite works ok. The second isn't. It outputs a 404, looks like is not mapping the https url to the php file.

Comment: Can you try with leading slash `RewriteRule ^login\.html$ /login.php`

Comment: Sure, no effect. I tried a lot of different things, looks like it doesn't know hot to map the url to a file when coming from https url instead of http.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120093/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-sh4).